# Send-MailMessage thorugh Office 365 operation times out

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, powershell-v5.0

I need to send an email report from a script. If I do this from one of our mail relays the email appears as [EXTERNAL]. Since this report includes links, I want users to trust it as coming internally.

I therefore want to use the `domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` SMTP connector, but when I do this I get `Send-MailMessage: The operation has timed out.`

This is the send mail line: `Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com -Port 587 -Credential $credential -From my.user@domain.com -To other.user@domain.com -Subject "External Test" -Body Test`

The `$credential` variable holds the output of `Get-Credential` which I logged in with my user account.

I've tried previously to get this to work, but gave up. I have also tried port 25 and Windows Powershell as well as Powershell 7.2.6.

SMTP Authentication is enabled for my user and companywide. I also tried smtp.office365.com as the server.

Comment: I would recommend to check if Send-MailMessage uses TLS/STARTTLS by default (because you have not added the `-UseSsl` option). Plain text connections are often disabled today so this could be a reason for the time out. And if TLS is used make sure the expected version is supported by your OS and is used https://stackoverflow.com/a/53785663/150978

Comment: I did miss the `-UseSsl` flag, but it made no difference. I always for get to specify the TLS version so I was hopeful that was my issue, however the results are the same :(

Comment: I've managed to get it working and it seems it was all of these things. The TLS version needed to be specified, I needed to add the `-UseSsl` option and switch to connecting to `smtp.office365.com` - WIthout all 3 it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the server you're running this script on is actually allowed by your network to connect to outside systemes on TCP port 587. You can use `Test-NetConnection` for this.

Also, as Robert said, add the `-UseSsl` switch to the command and [make sure to use TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785662/why-does-send-mailmessage-fail-to-send-using-starttls-over-port-587).

Comment: I cannot connect to port 587 from my corporate network, so I guess there is a firewall rule required here. However, I can also not connect from my home network where I don't have anythin gblocking me. I did miss the `-UseSsl` flag, but it made no difference. I always for get to specify the TLS version so I was hopeful that was my issue, however the results are the same :(

Comment: You should use`smtp.office365.com`.

Comment: I've managed to get it working and it seems it was all of these things. The TLS version needed to be specified, I needed to add the `-UseSsl` option and switch to connecting to `smtp.office365.com` - WIthout all 3 it wouldn't work.